# В Linux не высвобождается память

Tags: linux, centos

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня на сервере Linux работает программа. При этом каждый день увеличивается используемая ею оперативная память. Даже после остановки данной программы используемая оперативная память не уменьшается. Каким образом без перезагрузки компьютера высвободить используемую оперативную память. (В интернете нашёл только как высвободить буфер или кеш) Буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Использованный Рам увеличивается и работа данной программы замедляется. На сервере 32 Гб оперативной памяти - почти вся она используется. Может есть какая - нибудь утилита для высвобождения данной памяти?

Comment: А как вы смотрели потребление памяти? Чем конкретно у вас забито 32 ГБ?

Comment: я смотрю с помощью команды free -m

Comment: Не понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться. Есть сервер, есть софт, он выделяет память при работе. Вы не сможете отобрать у софта память. Сократить потребление памяти тоже не сможете. Если программа течет по памяти и выделяет постоянно больше, не освобождая - вы с этим ничего не сделаете со стороны ОС, только обновлением или исправлением этой текучей программы. Но для начала нужно четко и понятно доказать, что течет именно она, а не вы просто посмотрели 2 раза на память и увидели два разных числа в секции free. Изучите проблему, прежде чем решать.

Comment: Если кратко, то с вашим сервером все в порядке (я про память). Реальные проблемы начинаются тогда, когда нещадно пользуется swap. А у вас он свободен.

Comment: Эта проблема не одного дня - она постоянна при работе с данной программой. Я знаю, что можно изменив программу - всё можно изменить, но нет таких возможностей. Вы говорите всё в порядке с памятью, но я бы ничего не менял если бы данная программа работала нормально - я бы и не трогал эту память, но по мере увеличения этого числа - программа работает всё медленнее и медленнее.

Comment: я просто оставлю это здесь: http://linuxatemyram.ru/

Comment: Кто ещё может помочь?

Answer (score -1):

Должно решить проблему

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: Постарайтесь  вкратце написать, что именно происходит в системе при записи 3 в `drop_caches` (или  хотя бы дайте ссылку на документацию)